# Windows 7 Autoplay completely disabled - how to re-enable?

Tags: windows-7, autorun

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.

I am unable to use any of the Autoplay features.  I plug in a USB drive, pop in a CD, or connect a camera, and I get no reaction.

I need to restore the Autoplay function.  *How can I do this?*

Comment: Do you find an answer

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Change AutoPlay settings,

Adjust as required.

Comment: You can also get to this quickly from the start menu by typing 'autoplay' into the search box.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/27544-autoplay-enable-disable-autorun.html

Method 1:

```
1. Go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\AutoPlay.

To Enable:
At the top, check Use Autoplay for all devices and Click Save.

To Disable:
Uncheck Use Autoplay for all devices and Click Save.
```

Method 2:

```
1. Click Start and in the Search box, type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
Now browse to Computer Configuration\ Administrative Templates\ Windows Components\ Autoplay Policies\ Turn off Autoplay.

To Enable:
Change the value of Turn off Autoplay to disabled.


To Disable:
Change the value of Turn off Autoplay to enabled.
```

Comment: No effect with either method.

Comment: Answers with just a link are generally frowned upon. It can result in an accepted answer just having a dead link. Copy and paste the info in or put it in your own words. I imagine that's why you're getting downvotes

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Weltenwanderer! I'd suggest trying to give a little more background information or tutorial-like descriptions in your answers though. Your edit here is a great example of what a good answer should look like :-)

Answer (score 0):

Step One here:

> 1. Ensure that AutoPlay is used for all media type and devices
>
> Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs, and select Change AutoPlay settings, or Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> AutoPlay.
>
> AutoPlay Settings
>
> Ensure that the check box for Use AutoPlay for all media and devices is ticked (enabled).
>
> Enable and Turn On AutoPlay
>
> Then, make sure that for the devices and media that you want AutoPlay dialog to prompt, Ask me every time is selected. If other option is selected, Windows will automatically performing the action without prompting for selection.
>
> Alternatively, just click on Reset all defaults to reset and return AutoPlay settings to its original factory defaults.

**Steps continued here**:

> http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/08/11/fix-windows-7-autoplay-dialog-box-missing-or-not-appear-display-and-pop-up/

Comment: Answers with just a link are generally frowned upon. It can result in an accepted answer just having a dead link. Copy and paste the info in or put it in your own words. I imagine that's why you're getting downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you.....[try-out this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/08/11/fix-windows-7-autoplay-dialog-box-missing-or-not-appear-display-and-pop-up/)

On Microsoft site they have listed the following method

1. Click Start, type Gpedit.msc in the
   Start Search box, and then press
   ENTER.
2. If you are prompted for an
   administrator password or for
   confirmation, type the password, or
   click Allow.
3. Under Computer
   Configuration, expand Administrative
   Templates, expand Windows
   Components, and then click Autoplay
   Policies.
4. In the Details pane,see that the checkbox for Turn off Autoplay.
   is disabled
5. In the Details pane, check the
   Default Behavior for AutoRun.
6. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this to notepad and save as `whateveryouwant.bat`

This will only work if you run it as admin (the reason you need to run as admin is because this will edit the registry).

After you run this as admin, restart your computer and autorun should be enabled.

> @echo off set
>   key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer"
>
> reg add %key% /v NoDriveTypeAutoRun /t REG_DWORD /d 145